# Infinite HDL synthesis

Tags: vhdl, hdl, synthesis

Whenver I try to synthesize my code, it is caught in an infinite loop i.e it is stuck at HDL SYNTHESIS. I have not used any loops. But problem persists.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity mat is
  port(
    start,clck,start4,add4,check4,delete3,start3,add3,final3,load,load3,load4,search3:in std_logic;
    data1,data2,newitem:in std_logic_vector(0 to 8);
    completeload4tocontroller,completeadd3,search3cmplt,completeload3tocontroller,
    completeloadtocontroller,discerncomplete,complete4add,completedel3,step4comptocntrl:out bit;
    data4,data6:out std_logic_vector(0 to 15));
end mat;

architecture Behavioral of mat is

  type positiveelem is array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(0 to 18);
  type negativeelem is array (0 to 255) of std_logic_vector(0 to 18);
  signal poselem:positiveelem ;
  signal negelem:negativeelem ;
  signal pospointer:integer range 0 to 255:=0;
  signal negpointer:integer range 0 to 255:=0;
  signal jpst:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal jnst:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal jp1st:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal jp2st:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal jn4st:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal jp4st:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal j3pntr:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal j3npntr:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  signal j3ptr:integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  type list12 is array(0 to 65535) of integer range 0 to 31;
  signal clist:list12;
  signal limitcount:integer range 0 to 255 :=0;
  signal flag1:std_logic :='0';
  signal position:integer range 0 to 255;

begin

  P1:process(load,load4,clck,load3,check4,start,add4,start4,start3,delete3,add3)
    variable temp4:std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    variable temp5:std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    variable temp1:std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    variable tempp3:std_logic_vector(0 to 15);

  begin 
    if(rising_edge(clck))then

      if(load='1')then                           
        poselem(pospointer) <= data1;
        negelem(negpointer) <= data2;
        pospointer <= pospointer + 1;
        negpointer <= negpointer + 1;
        limitcount <= limitcount + 1;

        if(limitcount = 10)then      
          completeloadtocontroller <= '1'; 
        end if;  

      elsif((load4 = '1') and (load ='0'))then
        poselem(pospointer) <= newitem;
        pospointer <= pospointer + 1;
        completeload4tocontroller <= '1';

      elsif((load3 = '1') and (load = '0'))then
        negelem(negpointer) <= newitem;
        negpointer <= negpointer + 1;
        completeload3tocontroller <= '1';              

      elsif(start = '1')then 
        if((jpst <= pospointer) and (jnst <= negpointer))then
          temp4 := poselem(jpst)(0 to 15) xor negelem(jnst)(0 to 15);  
          clist(conv_integer(temp4)) <= clist(conv_integer(temp4)) + 1;

          if((jnst = (negpointer - 1)) and (jpst < (pospointer - 1)))then
            jnst <= 0;
            jpst <= jpst + 1;
          elsif(jnst < (negpointer - 1) and (jpst < (pospointer - 1)))then
            jnst <= jnst + 1;
          elsif(jpst = (pospointer - 1) and (jnst < (negpointer - 1)))then
            jnst <= jnst + 1;
          elsif((jp1st = pospointer) and (jp2st = pospointer) and
            (jpst = pospointer) and (jnst =  negpointer))then
            discerncomplete <= '1';
          end if;

        end if;    


      elsif(start4 = '1')then 
        if(add4 = '1')then
          temp1 := newitem(0 to 15) xor negelem(jn4st)(0 to 15);
          if(clist(conv_integer(temp1)) = 0)then
            data4 <= temp1;
          end if;

          clist(conv_integer(temp1)) <= clist(conv_integer(temp1)) + 1; 

          if(jn4st < (negpointer - 1))then
            jn4st <= jn4st + 1;
          elsif((jp4st = pospointer - 1) and (jn4st = negpointer - 1))then
            complete4add <= '1';
          end if;    
        end if;

      elsif(start3 = '1')then
        if(delete3 = '1')then
          if((poselem(position)(0 to 15) /= poselem(j3pntr)) 
              and (poselem(position)(16 to 18) /= poselem(j3pntr)(16 to 18)))then
            tempp3 := poselem(position)(0 to 15) xor poselem(j3pntr)(0 to 15);         
            if(clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) = 1)then
              data6 <= tempp3;
            end if;
            if(clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) /= 0)then
              clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) <= clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) - 1;
            end if;

            if(j3pntr < (pospointer - 1))then
              j3pntr <= j3pntr + 1;
            elsif((j3pntr = pospointer - 1) and (j3npntr = negpointer - 1))then
              completedel3 <= '1';
              poselem(position) <= "0000000000000000000";  
            end if;
          end if;

        elsif(search3 = '1')then 
          if((poselem(position)(16 to 18) /= newitem(16 to 18)) 
            and (poselem(position)(0 to 15) = newitem(0 to 15)))then 
            flag1 <= '1';
          end if;
          if((position < pospointer) and (flag1 = '0'))then
            position <= position + 1;
          elsif(flag1 = '1')then                
            search3cmplt <= '1';
          end if;   

        elsif(add3 = '1')then
          tempp3 := newitem(0 to 15) xor poselem(j3ptr)(0 to 15);
          if(clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) = 0)then
            data4 <= tempp3;
          end if;
          clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) <= clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) + 1;
          if(j3ptr < pospointer - 1 and (j3ptr = (position - 1)))then
            j3ptr <= j3ptr + 2;
          elsif(j3ptr = (pospointer - 1))then 
            completeadd3 <= '1';
          else
            j3ptr <= j3ptr + 1;                       
          end if;
        end if;    
      end if;
    end if;
    if(falling_edge(clck))then
      if(start = '1')then      
        if((jp1st /= pospointer) and (jp2st /= pospointer) and   (poselem(jp1st)(16 to 18) /= poselem(jp2st)(16 to 18)) 
            and (poselem(jp1st)(0 to 15) /= poselem(jp2st)(0 to 15))) then
          temp5 := poselem(jp1st)(0 to 15) xor poselem(jp2st)(0 to 15);
          clist(conv_integer(temp5)) <= clist(conv_integer(temp5)) + 1;           
        end if;

        if(jp1st < (pospointer - 1) and jp2st = (pospointer-1))then
          jp1st <= jp1st + 1;
          jp2st <= 0;
        elsif(jp1st = (pospointer - 1) and jp2st < (pospointer-1))then
          jp2st <= jp2st + 1;
        elsif(jp1st < (pospointer - 1) and jp2st < (pospointer-1))then
          jp2st <= jp2st + 1;
        elsif((jp1st = pospointer) and (jp2st = pospointer) and (jpst = pospointer) and (jnst = negpointer))then
          discerncomplete <= '1';
        end if;


    elsif(start4 = '1')then
      if(add4 = '1')then
        if((poselem(jp4st)(0 to 15) /= "0000000000000000"))then
          if(poselem(jp4st)(0 to 15) /= newitem(0 to 15)) 
              and (poselem(jp4st)(16 to 18) /= newitem(16 to 18)))then
            temp1 := newitem(0 to 15) xor poselem(jp4st)(0 to 15);
            if(clist(conv_integer(temp1)) = 0)then
              data4 <= temp1;
            end if;

            clist(conv_integer(temp1)) <= clist(conv_integer(temp1)) + 1; 
          end if;

          if(jp4st < (pospointer - 1))then
            jp4st <= jp4st + 1;
          elsif((jp4st = pospointer - 1) and (jn4st = negpointer - 1))then
            complete4add <= '1';
          end if;
        end if;     

      elsif(start3 = '1')then
        if(delete3 = '1')then
          tempp3 := newitem(0 to 15) xor negelem(j3npntr)(0 to 15);          
          if(clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) = 1)then
            data6 <= tempp3; 
          end if;
          if(clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) = 0)then
            clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) <= clist(conv_integer(tempp3)) - 1; 
          end if;
          if(j3npntr < negpointer - 1 )then     
            j3npntr <= j3npntr + 1;
          elsif((j3pntr = pospointer - 1) and (j3npntr = negpointer - 1))then
            completedel3 <= '1';
            poselem(position) <= "0000000000000000000";               
          end if;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;

  end process P1;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The software may be locking up because it's having trouble parsing your code. What software are you using? I re-indented it and discovered that you may have an if block you're not closing properly (specifically for `start = '1'` under `falling_edge(clck)`). Unless I copied and pasted wrong...

Comment: Actually, you have other syntax problems as well (there's an extra `)` around line 170 of what you posted, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

My comments address some of these issues, but I thought I'd type them up as an answer to add a little more detail and clarification.

Synthesis software getting stuck at a certain step and locking up has little to nothing to do with any particular language structure you're using, and probably means the software is having trouble parsing your code. While I would call this a bug in the software, you can probably get around it by looking for syntax errors (using another compiler, like ModelSim or something, might also help, if you have access). For instance, you appear to have an if-loop you're not closing somewhere under `if falling_edge(clck)`. You also have a missing `(` on the lines:

```
if(poselem(jp4st)(0 to 15) /= newitem(0 to 15)) 
    and (poselem(jp4st)(16 to 18) /= newitem(16 to 18)))then
```

And you're assigning `data1`, a 9-bit vector, to `poselem(pospointer)`, a 19-bit vector (and other similar assignments). Check your port and signal definitions.